# How to add a web elements to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a method in which I am trying to add 12 web elements:

```
private List<WebElement> iphoneSnippetList = new ArrayList<>();
@Test
public void test(){

    chromeDriver.get("https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/54726/list?hid=91491&glfilter=7893318%3A153043&onstock=1&local-offers-first=0");

        new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//article[@data-autotest-id='product-snippet'][1]")));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
            iphoneSnippetList.add((WebElement) By.xpath("//article[@data-autotest-id='product-snippet'][" + i + "]"));
        }
        System.out.println(iphoneSnippetList);
    }
```

Simplified DOM elements in which I only need to get the text :

```
<article class="_2vCnw cia-vs cia-cs" data-autotest-id="product-snippet"</article>
<article class="_2vCnw cia-vs cia-cs" data-autotest-id="product-snippet"</article>
<article class="_2vCnw cia-vs cia-cs" data-autotest-id="product-snippet"</article>
```

I need to add all 12 web elements to my array and then make sure that the received elements contain the name "Iphone", but when adding elements, there is exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iphoneSnippetList`  is a List of `WebElement` in Java-Selenium bindings.

I am not sure why you want to add 12 web elements using the loop, instead a `findElements` with right `xpath` would have been a good choice. Anyway, there's a problem with you code related to casting.

See below, `driver.findElement` will return the `web element`, and we are storing that into a `variable called Webelement e`, and **adding** the same into  `iphoneSnippetList`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//article[@data-autotest-id='product-snippet'][" + i + "]"));
    iphoneSnippetList.add(e);
}
    System.out.println(iphoneSnippetList);
```

Also, this loop will run for **13 times** not **12 times**. In case you want this to run for 12 times, initialize `i = 1` not `i = 0`

I think you will have issue with **xpath** also, cause you are not using `xpath` `indexing` correctly.

**try this instead :**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
     WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//article[@data-autotest-id='product-snippet'])['" +i+ "']"));
     iphoneSnippetList.add(e);
}
System.out.println(iphoneSnippetList);
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. How do you think it is correct to add elements?

Comment: Please see this section `try this instead :` above.